# Java, Regex match first 10 digits in String, disregard leading zeros

Tags: java, regex

I am interested to extract the first 10 digits if exists from a long string while disregarding the leading zeros. Additionally if there are only zeroes, return only 1 zero, if there no numbers, return empty string. I wish to match it in a single `find`.

For example:

- `"abcd00111.g2012asd"` should match to `"1112012"`
- `"aktr0011122222222222ddd"` should match to `"1112222222"`
- `"asdas000000asdasds0000"` should match to `"0"`
- `"adsads.cxzv.;asdasd"` should match to `""`

Here is what I have tried so far: [Ideone Demo - code](http://ideone.com/nSfnaY)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[1-9]{1}+[0-9]{9}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
  String match = m.group();
  System.out.println(match);
}
```

The problem is that this regex require 9 sequential digits after the first non zero, and I need any 9 digits (possible non digit chars in between).

Notice that in the code I have `if (m.find())` instead of `while (m.find())` because I wish to find the match in single run.

**UPDATE**

base on the comments i understood that it is not possible with regex to do it in single run.

I would like an answer not have to be regex based but most efficient since i will execute this method many times.

Comment: better post your code here

Comment: You can't have disconnected matches in regex and collecting all the data to capturing groups within lookaround would be tiring.

Comment: No, it is not possible with single find. You may be able do it with a limit on the number of contiguous sequence of digits, but not in general case. You need more than a single find.

Comment: This will be much easier without regular expressions: filter out all non-digits, trim leading zeros (except the last character), done.

Comment: @nhahtdh, not possible is also an answer , thanks all

Comment: Oh, and it *is* sort of possible with a regex, by capturing each of the 10 digits, something like: `^[\D0]*(\d)\D*(?:(\d)\D*(?:(\d)\D*(?:(\d)\D*(?#{6 more times}))?)?)?`, but it is really ugly, and doesn't scale well.

Comment: @Kobi, Thanks looks interesting ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>In general case, it is not possible to do it with a single `find`. You can do it if you know the maximum number of contiguous sequence of digits, but if that is not known, then it is not possible, at least at the level of support of Java `Pattern` class.</s> I was wrong about this. [Kobi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105672/java-regex-match-first-10-digits-in-string-disregard-leading-zeros/15105896#comment21253648_15105672) shows that it is possible with a single regex. I will reproduce the comment here:

> Oh, and it is sort of possible with a regex, by capturing each of the 10 digits, something like: `^[\D0]*(\d)\D*(?:(\d)\D*(?:(\d)\D*(?:(\d)\D*(?#{6 more times}))?)?)?`, but it is really ugly, and doesn't scale well.

You still need to concatenate the groups, though. The logic in the regex at the beginning is quite nice: due to the greedy property, it will search for the first non-zero digit that are after all the leading zero if any, or it will take the last 0 if there is no non-zero digit.

---

If you throw the talk about efficiency out of the door, and you want short code:

```
String digitOnly = str.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
String noLeadingZero = digitOnly.replaceFirst("^0+", "");
String result = digitOnly.isEmpty() ? "" :
                noLeadingZero.isEmpty() ? "0" : 
                noLeadingZero.substring(0, Math.min(noLeadingZero.length(), 10));
```

---

Frankly, a loop through the string, with a `StringBuilder` is good enough, and it should be faster than regex solution.

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
boolean hasDigit = false;
boolean leadingZero = true;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() && output.length() < 10; i++) {
    char currChar = str.charAt(i);
    if ('0' <= currChar && currChar <= '9') {
        hasDigit = true;
        if (currChar != '0') {
            output.append(currChar);
            leadingZero = false;
        } else if (!leadingZero) { // currChar == 0
            output.append(currChar);
        } // Ignore leading zero
    }
}

String result = !hasDigit ? "" :
                output.length() == 0 ? "0" :
                output.toString();
```

[**Performance testing code**](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5046416). Note that you should adjust the parameters to make it resemble actual input so that you get a good approximation. I doubt looping method is slower than anything involving regex; however, the difference is only significant on large scale.

Comment: +1, This looks good solution , is it the most efficient one (since i will run it many many time on different strings)

Comment: @Michael: Just edited my post. There was some stupid bug in my first piece of code.

Comment: @Michael: Most efficient? I need to write a test for it (I need around 10 mins). I am not totally sure, but the second method should be faster than the regex method.

Answer (score 2):

```
String test = "sdfsd0000234.432004gr23.022";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<test.length();i++) {
    if(Character.isDigit(test.charAt(i))) 
        sb = sb.append(test.charAt(i));
}
String result = sb.toString();
result = result.replaceFirst("^0*", "");  //Remove leading zeros
System.out.println(result);               //Will print 23443200423022
```

Comment: +1 Yes , thanks, i wonder which is more faster solution when executing this function many many times on different strings

Comment: Concatenation with `+` is slow. Use `StringBuilder` instead.